# SQL filter on multiple matches from join

Tags: sql, join, filter, where-clause

Lets say I have the following data;

```
Person
 1. John
 2. Anne
 3. Will
```

```
PersonAnimals
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
3 2
```

```
Animal
1. Cat
2. Dog
3. Fish
```

Now I can query all data like this;

```
SELLECT *
FROM Person p
JOIN PersonAnimal pa ON pa.PersonId = p.Id
JOIN Animal a ON pa.AnimalId = a.Id;
```

But now I would like to query every person that has a Cat **AND** a Dog. (in the example only John matches that filter) Can you do this in SQL? an how?

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: my expected result is John, as I say in the last line :)

Comment: That's _describing_ the result, not _specifying_ it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation can help here:

```
SELLECT p.*
FROM Person p JOIN
     PersonAnimal pa
     ON pa.PersonId = p.Id JOIN
     Animal a
     ON pa.AnimalId = a.Id
WHERE a.species IN ('cat', 'dog')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.species) = 2;  -- both are present
```

Note:  In some databases, you will need to include all columns in the `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY`.  The above is compliant with  Standard SQL assuming that `person.id` is the primary key (or unique).